# cordova - Alert That If I Click Ok Crashes broswer

Tags: cordova, crash, popup, alert

I am trying to run my app in an iOS device. The weird popup appear that say the follow :

```
gap:["PluginManager","startup","PluginManager307573941"]
```

If I click OK, the browser crashes. If I click cancel, everything works. This happens in the `iOS` simulator only, in android it works without that popup.

I used this script:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>`

I have to cancel popup and would really love to understand the reasoning. Thanks

Comment: Please give us more information about your app. If you share some code maybe, it's became easier to help you.

Comment: It seems that your Cordova isn't initializing correctly as native app because of something. I've seen that happening when all plugins haven't been installed for that platform.

Comment: yea cordova features wont work on browser. if you want to test ui then comment out cordova.js . but if u want to test cordova events,apis then you need to run them on emulator or device. if you click on cancel(many popups will be displayed) it wont crash browser.